# How do I find out who is sharing their screen on Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

During a call, it is almost impossible to know who is sharing their screen on a Teams call. Is there a way to find out which participant is sharing their screen?
I am on the latest version as of 3rd Feb 22. Googling hasn't helped me find an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the name is floating in the bottom left of the shared screen.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst in the call, bring up the participants list. The person presenting will have the red circle with a line through (quite hard to see though)

[image]

All other participants will just have a red circle unless they manually change their status to something else.

As well as that, as Virsacer has said, their name is in a label bottom-left corner of the Teams window.